# Why XmlPullParser don't read empty strings on android

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I serialize array of strings to XML, my output:

```
<MyArray>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">testString</anyType>
    <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string"></anyType> // here is empty string, and I want it in output array
</MyArray>
```

When I try to deserialize this back to array with XMLPullParser it's create array only with one string.
Why function next() from XmlPullParser on second string only return START_TAG and END_TAG, without TEXT event?
There is any workaround to get empty string from this xml?

Comment: I think the String can take null as the value. Are you sure you are putting the value in String variable and not using String array? Try having a white-space instead of empty String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html,
more specifically the [nextText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#nextText%28%29) method documentation, you get:

> If current event is START_TAG then if next element is TEXT then
>   element content is returned or if next event is END_TAG then empty
>   string is returned, otherwise exception is thrown. After calling this
>   function successfully parser will be positioned on END_TAG. The
>   motivation for this function is to allow to parse consistently both
>   empty elements and elements that has non empty content.

The sample code they provide works well, and I'm currently using in my code something in the lines of:

```
mPullParser.nextTag();
mPullParser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, tag);
final String text = mPullParser.nextText();
mPullParser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, null, tag);
```

Which works just fine, regardless it's an empty string or not. Are you using the `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser` library?

Comment: Yes I use org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, I will try your solution.